# Dialog boxes not appearing

Tags: macbook-pro

I just installed Ubuntu 18 on my old 2012 Macbook pro, everything works fine, except for that the standard dialog boxes does not appear, like "Save as" from Libreoffice, or open file from any Chrome web page to upload something.
The dialog box is somewhere because it lets me save a file simply by pressing enter, but there is nothing in the UI.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Okay I figured it out.

Your display is set to Join Displays...  Change it to Single Display..

The dialog box was showing up on the other screen.

Open settings > Devices > Display > Click tab 'Single Display'

Viola